# Type 'AxiosResponse<IUser, any>' is not an array type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I have a some small problem with typing axios response.
I have method that return user profile from API:

```
 static async getProfileById(id: string | undefined){
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

    const response = await axios.get<IUser>(`http://localhost:4000/api/feed/id?id=${id}`, {
        headers: {
            authorization: "Bearer " + jwt
        }
    })

    return response;
}
```

interface IUser:

```
export interface IPost{
    _id: string,
    title: string,
    body: string,
    viewed: number,
    likes: number,
    comments: number,
    author: string,
    image: string,
    __v: number,
    date: string,
    isLiked: boolean
}
```

I create const that I put user profiles:
`const [subs, setSubs] = useState<IUser[]>([]);`

And there I adding profiles to const subs:

```
for (let i =0; i < response.length; i++){
    const profileSub = await UserService.getProfileById(response[i]);

    console.log(typeof profileSub);

    setSubs([...subs, ...profileSub])
}
```

But I got error : 'Type 'AxiosResponse<IUser, any>' is not an array type'.

What am I doing wrong?
Thx.

Comment: You're trying to spread something you told the compiler _wasn't_ an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subs` is an array of type `IUser[]` and `profileSub` is an object of type `IUser`. You cannot spread an object into an array. If you want to add `profileSub` to the `subs` array, you would do:

```
setSubs(prevSubs => [...prevSubs, profileSub])
```

Simply add the `profileSub` into the new `subs` array without spreading it.

**Note**: if you want to return the user profile from `getProfileById`, you have to return `response.data`.